# How to make overflow: auto container follow list-item iteratation

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, iteration, listitem

I have a div container set to `overflow:auto` which contains many `<li>`'s.  I wrote a simple function to change the highlighted list-item when the user clicks a button or presses the up or down arrows.

The only problem is when the user clicks the iteration button the highlighted list-item iterates without the container scrollbar following it.  I'm looking for a way to force the container scrollbar to scroll with the iteration

here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/rwfUr/

Remember - up and down arrows make the container scroll (as long as the container has focus) but the iteration button does not.

**Important** - I am looking for an alternative to .scrollTo()

Comment: What about [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)?

Comment: What about [.scrollIntoView()](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=scrollintoview) ?

Comment: ++Andy - best solution I've seen yet.  This is what it amounts to http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/rwfUr/16/  Thanks!

Comment: @Andy, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [.scrollIntoView()](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=scrollintoview) ?

Comment: ended up going with scrollIntoView() it is pretty clean and seems to work as requested. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically do this, you would need to get the height of an item and the height of the box.

When to scroll: **(height of box - (highlighted item number * item height) < 0)**
Use the scrollTop property to scroll the list by the items height, while the above is less then 0.

I hope this helps.

**:: Edit ::**
This will only work if the box height is exactly the size of a specified number of list items. Let's say each of the items heights are 20px and you want the listbox to show 10 items, then you would need to set the listbox height to 200px.

Comment: with this in mind could you look at this and tell me why .offset().top keeps jumping around? http://jsfiddle.net/sadmicrowave/rwfUr/14/

Comment: Aelux - well, while my container will always be a specified height, I will have an unknown amount of list-items inside.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many items you have in the list, as long as the list box is a fixed size, in proportion to the list items that you're able to view at one time. As far as your first comment goes, your offsetTop needs to use the formula I explained above, to work. You would need to add the height of an item to the offsetTop instead of setting it to equal.

Remember though, you only need to scroll when the algorithm mentioned above is below zero.